# How to change the textAppearance of a checked RadioButton with XML?

Tags: android

I have a RadioButton.

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonOne"
            style="@style/RadioButtonCustom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pertinence" />
```

And a style.

```
<style name="RadioButtonCustom" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/radiobutton_color</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to change the text appeareance like the text size or the font family of the radio button only if it's checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. You can use text **appearance** like so:

```
    radiobtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rbTextColor));
    radiobtn.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but the answer is completely off-topic. I want to change the size of the text not the color of the text (and I've already done it with <item name="android:textColor">@color/radiobutton_color</item>).

Comment: @Asue are u using java or kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin. Thank you for this solution with the code, I will wait to see if there are other answers to do it via XML directly.

Comment: how you can check if its selected in xml for that use have to use backend bro!

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/radiobutton check this its has lots of information about radio button.